# cut array from a specific character

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this in `$array[0]:`

```
attack-responses.rules?rev=1.35&content-type=text/vnd.viewcvs-markup
```

I want to have this in `$array[0]`

```
attack-responses.rules
```

I mean when it will see '?' it must cut it.

Is there any PHP function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse-url)

```
$array[0] = parse_url($array[0], PHP_URL_PATH);
```

or [`list()`](http://php.net/list)/[`explode()`](http://php.net/explode)

```
list($array[0]) = explode('?', $array[0], 2);
```

or [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr)/[`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos)

```
$array[0] = substr($array[0], 0, strpos($array[0], '?'))
```

Answer (score 0):

look there at the documentation of [parse_url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
$str="attack-responses.rules?rev=1.35&content-type=text/vnd.viewcvs-markup";
$url=parse_url($str));
$array[0]=$url['path'];
```